# How to get content from email sent to your lamp server

Tags: php, apache, email

Say I have my own server, and I want to send an email that's reads "hello World" to my site, submit@example.com

Is there a way to automatically extract the text "hello world" and post the content to my website?

I believe I can read a file with PHP, and the file can be created by apache for every incoming email... but I'm missing some knowledge here

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have PHP act as an email client. Take a look at PHP IMAP (which actually works for POP too) http://php.net/manual/en/intro.imap.php

While emails are almost always stored on disk as files, accessing those files directly would not be advisable unless you were writing a new email server (I've contemplated that actually, but it is definitely NOT a trivial task) and your web server (e.g., PHP running in Apache) wouldn't have that level of access. The basic steps the right way are:

1. Add the email account, set the password, etc. Decide whether you want to access it as IMAP (emails stick around unless you delete and then empty the trash, which lets you archive on the server and/or access from other devices) or POP (typically "read the emails and delete from the server immediately").
2. Write PHP code to read the mail account. The specifics will vary slightly depending on the email server/hosting configuration. You may need to work at it a bit until you can successfully read a list of messages.
3. Once you are able to read the messages, you will likely need to handle multiple formats. In particular, messages may come in as plain text or as mime parts. There can be quite a bit of variation depending on the software used to write the original message, so to test you may want to send in messages using Outlook, Thunderbird and other programs.
4. You will also likely need to filter out HTML tags and other extraneous stuff from legitimate messages AND you will inevitably have to come up with a way to block spam. If you only accept messages from registered users then you can verify based on the From: address (at least as a start, because that can be spoofed too...) but if the support email address is "open" then filtering the junk can be quite a challenge.

This is a non-trivial project, but I have successfully set up a few systems of this type, though typically with controls to help block spam (e.g., required codes in the Subject line; limited "From" addresses).